# How do you create persistant IntelliJ variables in run configurations in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ 15.0.3.
Update: Have also tried updating to 2016.2.4, but the issue persists.

By creating variables under Settings -> Appearence and Behaviour -> Path Variables, these can be used in a run configuration with $VARIABLE_NAME$ to indicate for example what working directory or program arguments should be used by that run configuration. This is useful if for example the same directory is used in many parts of the run configuration but is changed from run to run.

However when using $VARIABLE_NAME$ in a run configuration it doesn't seem to be persistant. If I close my IntelliJ session the value of the variable will replace the variable reference. So for example if I have the variable:

```
FILENAME = somefile.csv
```

and in my run configuration I put "$FILENAME$" under program arguments, this will only be persistant for that session. When I close and reopen IntelliJ the program argument has been set to "somefile.csv" instead of retaining the reference "$FILENAME$".

How do I ensure that the variable reference is retained over several sessions?

Edit: Added screenshots showing before and after session reset.

Before a session reset I set my program arguments to reference my FILENAME variable. This also happens if I try to for example use the working directory field instead of the program arguments field.
[image]

After restarting IntelliJ the run configuration no longer references FILENAME.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the issue in v2016.2.4 (i.e. I still get the replacement value after a restart). You may want to [upgrade to v15.0.6](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Previous+IntelliJ+IDEA+Releases) which is the latest v15.x available and see if that resolves the issue.

The values you set are simply stored in the file *.IntelliJIdea\config\options\path.macros.xml* (see [Directories used by the IDE to store settings, caches, plugins and logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519) for info on where the `configs` directory is located.) So you can take a look at that file and see what's going on. Maybe try adding it outside IDEA (when IDEA is closed) and see if it holds (in the event a bug is causing the that file to not save properly after editing via the IDE.)

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue in v2016.2.4. I checked the path.macros.xml file, and there is nothing fishy there. However I wouldn't expect that since the path variables themselves remain intact for me between sessions. It's the references that are not persistant.